# Is it possible to override a local .npmrc when running `npm install`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, npm

My project has an .npmrc located in its root, which contains the infamous [${NPM_TOKEN}](http://blog.getpiggybank.com/npm-private-modules-with-heroku/) hack and is required for CI, Staging, Production, etc.

In order to work around this reality, I'd like for developers to be able to tell `npm` to use an alternative .npmrc, which contains *their* `_authToken`, when installing dependencies. Something like, `npm install . --npmrc=~/.npmrc`. This would prevent them from having to pollute their system's environment variables, .bash_profile, etc.

Is this currently possible? (Doesn't seem so...) If not, are there any reasons why such an approach either wouldn't be possible (highly unlikely) or wouldn't be considered by the NPM team?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As luck would have it, [this option already exists](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#userconfig) and can be used like so:

```
npm install . --userconfig=~/.npmrc
```

Comment: This will set user user specific configuration which will still be overridden by local project specific .npmrc wouldn't it?

Comment: This configuration just changes the location where user specific npm config file should be found not the priority
 At least I think so. Pls let is know if it worked

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. When I run `npm --userconfig=~/.npmrc whoami` from within a project that has a `$PROJECT/.npmrc` it still shows the username from the project, not my user config.

Comment: I've opened a new question for this, here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57045297/71522

Answer (score 16):

I have a similar issue, my solution is to rename the project level .npmrc into something like .npmrc-ci, so that it doesn't mess with local environment, while in ci script add `mv .npmrc-ci .npmrc` before running any npm command.

Comment: interesting - do you do this in docker build command Lin or Dockerfile?

Comment: This answer was perfect at resolving this issue for me! Added it to our BitBucket pipeline and works like a charm.

Comment: This is perfect :) Thank you Chris