# Override npm project auth token with user auth token?

Tags: npm

I've got a project that includes a `$PROJECT/.npmrc` that has an auth token granting read-only access to the proviat repos required by the project:

```
$ cat .npmrc
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken={read-only-token}
```

How can I override that token with my user token so I can publish packages?

```
$ cat ~/.npmrc
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken={my-token}
```

The [documentation states](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc#files) that config files will be loaded in "priority order", where the project configuration has the highest priority, and there doesn't seem to be any way to override this:

```
$ cd my-project/
$ npm whoami
project-readonly-user
$ cd ~
$ npm whoami
wolever
```

I know that it's possible to define an `NPM_TOKEN` environment variable:

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}
```

But this means that every user of the project will need to define the `NPM_TOKEN` environment variable, which is undesirable (ie, because it means that every user - including read-only users - will need to define an `NPM_TOKEN` environment variable before they can use the project).

Answer (score 2):

Just found a solution.

Edit your `.npmrc` file:

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}
```

Every time you want to publish(powershell):

```
$env:NPM_TOKEN="the-token"
npm publish --access public --registry https://registry.npmjs.org
```

Answer (score 1):

CLI arguments have precedence over local .npmrc config, so you could overwrite it this way:

```sh
npm publish --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken={my-token}
```

You could add an npm script for publishing that depends on an environment variable with a private token:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "publish": "npm publish --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_PUBLISH_TOKEN}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the docs have change and setting the auth Token via CLI is not possible anymore on [npm publish](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-publish), so I provide more solution for using NPM with Github Actions + Font Awesome PRO + Github Package Registry:

```yaml
name: Node.js Package
on:
    release:
        types: [created]
    workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
    publish:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        permissions:
            contents: read
            packages: write
        steps:
            - name: Checkout 
              uses: actions/checkout@master

            - name: Setup node env 
              uses: actions/setup-node@v2
              with:
                  node-version: '14.x'
                  registry-url: 'https://npm.pkg.github.com'
                  scope: '@mindfuel'

            - name: Install Packages 
              run: npm ci
              env:
                  NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

            - name: Build 
              run: npm run build

            - name: Prepare NPM Config ‍♂️
              run: rm -f .npmrc

            - name: Setup publishing Env 
              uses: actions/setup-node@v2
              with:
                  node-version: '14.x'
                  registry-url: 'https://npm.pkg.github.com'
                  scope: '@mindfuel'

            - name: Publish Package 
              run: npm publish
              env:
                  NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

For me the trick is to recall setup-node after deleting the existing .npmrc.

We have a shared .npmrc that all developers use. It includes a *READ ONLY* token to our companies registry:

```
# Font Awesome Pro Config
@fortawesome:registry=https://npm.fontawesome.com/
//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken=<your-token>

# Private Packages
@<github-username-or-org>:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=<the-read-only-token>
```